# Looking for PS command to silently execute a program on user login

Tags: powershell

New PS user here...been looking around on some tutorials for basic PS commands before wasting anyone's time here.

Trying to write script that executes a program on user login. On an enterprise network and tier 3 has disabled much of the customization for users and tier 1 (me). Boss wants Teams to open when he logs in (he's old and his attention is everywhere but in front of his face).

I wrote this to open the exe...

`& c:\users\username\appdata\local\microsoft\teams\current\teams.exe`

...and then tried this to keep a PS window from flashing...

`& c:\users\username\appdata\local\microsoft\teams\current\teams.exe 'echo foo'`

...but that only kept the command from showing when the window flashed.

Any advices?

Comment: You are calling a shell/app. All have a splash screen or popup. You have to add more code to your script. There are several examples on the web regarding how to suppress the flash. Just search for that.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me. I had to run the powershell terminal with administrator privileges though.

```bsh
$Sta = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute "Cmd"
$Stt = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -AtLogon
Register-ScheduledTask Task01 -Action $Sta -Trigger $Stt
```

Code copied from [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/scheduledtasks/new-scheduledtasktrigger?view=win10-ps#example-5--register-a-scheduled-task-that-starts-when-a-user-logs-on). It uses the built in Windows Task Scheduler and registers a new task that will be executed for any local user at logon. The Task Scheduler also has a GUI and you can setup this task without powershell.

Comment: This does not completely/consistantly prevent the flash. You have to write more code in the script to do this.